# How to edit/use existing ArcMap process by separate stand-alone application

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#

I am trying to create an executable which does the following.

1. Accepts 3 arguments
2. Finds local ArcMap process. Brings process window to foreground.
3. Uses ArcMap session to query 3 arguments and zoom to specific location.

I am able to do everything except #3. I do not know how to identify arcmap. the bottom section of code works when the code is built as an ESRI add-in but this is an executable which is run outside of arcgis. can someone let me know what I can do to fix this?

> Error 3   The name 'ArcMap' does not exist in the current context

```
public class ZoomToGeo : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
{

    static string FeatClassName;
    static string QueryFieldName;
    static string UNIQUE_ID;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length == 3)
            {
                FeatClassName = args[0].ToString().ToUpper();
                QueryFieldName = args[1].ToString().ToUpper();
                UNIQUE_ID = args[2].ToString();

                Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("ArcMap");
                if (p.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Process i in p)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ShowWindow(i.MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
                            SetForegroundWindow(i.MainWindowHandle);
                            ArcMap.Events.OpenDocument += new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_OpenDocumentEventHandler(zoomToPOI);
                        }
                        catch (Exception Ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Foreground, zoom to point" + Ex.Message);
                        }
                    }                                      
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Main Thread:\n" + Ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void zoomToPOI()
    {
        IFeatureLayer FeatLayer;
        IFeatureClass FeatClass;
        ILayer TargetLayer = null;
        IFeatureClass TargetFeatClass = null;
        IFeature TargetFeature;
        IQueryFilter QF = new QueryFilterClass();
        IFeatureCursor FeatCur;
        IApplication App = ArcMap.Application;
        IMxDocument MxDoc = (IMxDocument)App.Document;
        IMap CurrMap = MxDoc.FocusMap;
        IActiveView ActView = MxDoc.ActiveView;
        IDisplay Disp = ActView.ScreenDisplay;
        IEnumLayer Layers = CurrMap.Layers;
        ILayer Layer = Layers.Next();

        while (Layer != null)
        {
            if (Layer is IFeatureLayer)
            {
                FeatLayer = (IFeatureLayer)Layer;
                FeatClass = FeatLayer.FeatureClass;
                if (FeatClass.AliasName.ToUpper() == FeatClassName)
                {
                    TargetLayer = Layer;
                    TargetFeatClass = FeatClass;
                }
            }
            Layer = Layers.Next();
        }
        if (TargetFeatClass != null)
        {
            QF.WhereClause = QueryFieldName + " = \'" + UNIQUE_ID + "\'";
            FeatCur = TargetFeatClass.Search(QF, false);
            TargetFeature = FeatCur.NextFeature();
            if (TargetFeature != null)
            {
                CurrMap.ClearSelection();
                CurrMap.SelectFeature(TargetLayer, TargetFeature);
                ActView.Refresh();

                //Zoom to Selected
                UID ZTS_UID = new UIDClass();
                ZTS_UID.Value = "esriArcMapUI.ZoomToSelectedCommand";
                App.Document.CommandBars.Find(ZTS_UID).Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                //target feature couldn't be found. Notify and exit.
                MessageBox.Show("A feature in " + FeatClassName + " with " + QueryFieldName + " of " + UNIQUE_ID + " could not be found.");
            }

        }
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {

    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

}
```

Comment: I suggest looking into [IAppROT](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IAppROT.htm) and perhaps also [IObjectFactory](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#iobjectfactory.htm).

Comment: @Midavalo ArcMap 10.2.2

Comment: I'd actually hope that step #3 is impossible, since being able to take over a running application and force it to do things it was not prepared to do would be a ***HUGE*** security hole in Windows.  You could make an add-in/extension DLL which enabled this sort of interprocess communication, and that would be considered a security threat as well, but at least it would be a proactive step to allow that type of communication.

Comment: What you are talking about is _Automation_, you hook into a running instance ArcMap through the IAppROT interface.

Comment: @Vince one can always hope, but I think this is <del>flaw</del> feature exists.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably mixing up different things.

On the one hand you can create and ESRI Add-in (for example an Extension derived from `ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension`). These Add-Ins are intended for a use inside a running ArcGIS application as an extension (inside the ArcMap process space). How the Add-In appears and when it is loaded in an ArcMap session can be steered by the file `Config.esriaddinx`. From the Add-In you have nearly full control of the ArcMap application and the MXD.

On the other hand you can create a stand alone application. This has nothing to do with the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension`. Please have a look at 
the [Building stand-alone applications](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#63adc7b8-887b-4b2b-8373-de14e6fb64bd.htm) for a quick overview about different application types.

In your case I guess you want to have your own application which steers an own ArcMap process. Please have a look at [Automating ArcGIS for Desktop applications](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#56eba175-54c1-46b4-801a-fc968e582581.htm) for details. Please have a detailed look at the notes at the bottom of this article.

Another option as Kirk and Hornbydd already mentioned is to use the `IAppROT`. Here you'll need to reference `ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework` and `ESRI.ArcGIS.Display`. Please try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Initialisieren der ESRI Lizenz
    bool LicenseKo = m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor },
        new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeMLE, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeDataInteroperability });
    if (!LicenseKo)
    {
        IAppROT myAppROT = new AppROTClass();
        for (int i = 0; i < myAppROT.Count; i++)
        {
            IApplication theApp = myAppROT.Item[i] as IApplication;
            if (theApp != null)
            {
                IMxDocument mxDoc = theApp.Document as IMxDocument;
                IMap theMap = mxDoc.FocusMap;
            }
        }
        m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
    }
}
```

Comment: This can fail if ArcCatalog is running.